# Subtraction of two SELECT statements in SQL (redshift)

Tags: sql, group-by, count, amazon-redshift, sql-null

Can someone explain why the below doesn't work?

```
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) - (SELECT Count(Metric) FROM Table1)) as X
```

Count(*) will give me all the rows in the table and Count(Metric) will give me the non-null values in the Metric column. So the difference between these will give me the number of null values in the Metric column and I have labelled this column X. I just want the difference between the two in Column X but not sure why it isn't working.

By the way, I know I can get it to work via the below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as a, count(metric) as b, COUNT(*)-COUNT(metric) as c
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to `select` the result:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) - (SELECT Count(Metric) FROM Table1)) as X
```

But it is simpler to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Metrics IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) X FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

A `SELECT` query needs to start with `SELECT` (or `WITH` or a parenthesis if the query is a compound query with a set operator such as `UNION ALL`).

One method is:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) - (SELECT Count(Metric) FROM Table1)) as X
```

A better method is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - Count(Metric) as X
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about amazon-redshift, but in standard SQL I would just count the records where the field is null instead of counting all minus where they are not null.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Metric IS NULL;
```